# AWS SDK - No such file or Directory

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cloud9

I followed this AWS Sdk setup for C++ on Cloud9 exactly:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/sample-cplusplus.html

I stumped on **Step 6: Build and Run the AWS SDK Code** after I ran the commands:

`cmake -Daws-sdk-cpp_DIR=sdk_build .`

then

`make`

Unfortunately, I keep receiving the following error:

`/home/ubuntu/environment/s3-demo.cpp:2:10: fatal error: aws/core/Aws.h: No such file or directory #include <aws/core/Aws.h>`

I've tried all 3 Linux environments that AWS has to offer but I still receive the same error. I suspect there's something wrong with my `CMakeLists.txt` file but I'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated. I've spent too many hours on this already.